# QML OpenGL plugin not redrawing at 60Hz

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

### The Situation

My company has a QML-based application which displays some content using a custom OpenGL-based render plugin (`MyGame`). This plugin has a few critical needs:

1. To be able to effect changes in the renderer in response to QML-based signals.
   (e.g. change the position of an object rendered by the game)
2. To only process these changes at a specific spot in MyGame's redraw loop.
   (This is very important; MyGame is very sensitive about when changes are allowed.)
3. **To have the plugin redraw at 60Hz (at least).**

### The Problem

The code we have right now honors (1) and (2), but fails (3); the plugin does not get visually updated consistently. (The updates are erratic, at an estimated 5-10Hz.) I believe that the plugin we have created—based on `QQuickFramebufferObject`—is not taking proper advantage of how Qt/QML intended the scene graph to be updated.

**How can I re-structure my plugin so that I get all three of the above?**

### The Code

Overview:

- The plugin creates a `QQuickFramebufferObject` (`MyPlugin`) and a `QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer` (`MyRenderer`).
- When `MyRenderer::render()` is called it calls `MyGame::Redraw()` itself, and then calls `update()`.
- `MyGame::Redraw()` does what it needs to, and at the right spot where changes can be accepted, emits a `timeToMakeChanges` QML signal on `MyPlugin`.
- QML listens for the `onTimeToMakeChanges` signal and invokes methods on the plugin that affect MyGame.

To workaround the problem of low-frequency visual updates, I've found that if I overlay a QML `Canvas` over my plugin and redraw the canvas frequently using a `Timer`, my plugin starts to get visually updated at what appears to be around 60Hz. Clearly this is a gross hack.

Following is a summary of the code setup. Please forgive missing/incorrect code; I'm trying to distill thousands of lines of glue code down to the essentials for this question.

**MyPlugin.h**

```c
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QQuickFramebufferObject>

class MyPlugin : public QQuickFramebufferObject {
Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyPlugin();
  virtual ~MyPlugin();
  virtual QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer* createRenderer() const;

signals:
  void timeToMakeChanges();

public slots:
  void makeChanges(QVariant inValue);
  void HandleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *inWindow);

private:
  MyGame* GetGame() { ... }
};
```

**MyPlugin.cpp**

```c
#include "MyPlugin.h"
#include <MyGame.h>

// ******************************************************************

class MyRenderer:
  public QObject,
  public QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer,
  protected QOpenGLFunctions
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
  virtual void render();

private:
  static void RequestGameChanges();
};

void MyRenderer::render() {

  if ( !m_Initialized ) {
    QOpenGLFramebufferObject *theFbo = this->framebufferObject();
    InitializeGl( theFbo ); // Not shown
    m_MyGame = &MyGame::Create();
    m_MyGame->RegisterCallback(
      reinterpret_cast<qml_Function>(MyRenderer::RequestGameChanges)
    );
    m_Initialized = true;
  }

  m_MyGame->RestoreState();
  m_MyGame->Redraw();
  m_MyGame->SaveState();
  m_PluginItem->window()->resetOpenGLState();

  // Tell QML that we want to render again as soon as possible
  update();
}

// This gets invoked in the middle of m_MyGame->Redraw()
void MyRenderer::RequestGameChanges() {
  emit m_PluginItem->timeToMakeChanges();
}

// ******************************************************************

MyPlugin::MyPlugin() {
  setMirrorVertically(true);
  connect(
    this, SIGNAL(windowChanged(QQuickWindow*)),
    this, SLOT(HandleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow*))
  );
}

void MyPlugin::HandleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *inWindow) {
  inWindow->setClearBeforeRendering(false);
}

void MyPlugin::makeChanges(QVariant inValue) {
  MyGame *theGame = GetGame();
  // Send the requested changes to theGame
}

QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer* MyPlugin::createRenderer() const {
  m_Renderer = new MyRenderer( *this );
}
```

**MyApp.qml**

```qml
import MyPlugin 1.0
Window {
  MyPlugin {
    property var queuedUpChanges: ([])
    onSomeOtherSignal:   queueUpChangesToMake();
    onTimeToMakeChanges: makeChanges( queuedUpChanges );
  }
  Canvas { id:hack }
  Timer {
    interval:10; running:true; repeat:true
    onTriggered: hack.changeWhatYouShow();
  }
}
```

### Bonus Points

The main question is ***"How do I modify my code so that I get 60Hz updates?"*** However, as seen in the QML, the setup above requires me to queue up all changes in QML so that they are able to be applied during the right spot in the `MyGame::Render()`.

Ideally, I'd prefer to write QML without `timeToMakeChanges`, like:

```qml
MyPlugin {
  onSomeOtherSignal: makeChanges( ... );
}
```

If there's a way to accomplish this (other than queuing up the changes in C++ instead)—perhaps something related to `synchronize()` I'd love to know about it.

Comment: It's currently a `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` between `timeToMakeChanges` and `onTimeToMakeChanges`?

Comment: @Velkan I wish I knew. The code is as you see there: we *just* emit a `timeToMakeChanges` signal from C++ and let QML handle it via `onTimeToMakeChanges`. I don't know how to know, or control, what type of connection that is.

Comment: Then it's `Qt::QueuedConnection`. The `RequestGameChanges()` (which is in the render thread) just enqueues a signal to the event loop of the GUI/QML thread, and proceeds with any data it has. Add a log to `MyRenderer::render()` to trace the fps of that renderer. If it's 60 without the `Canvas`, then the problem is not with the rendering thread. Also, see what fps is without actual rendering (maybe there are locks inside the `MyGame` class).

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a timer in QML that calls the `makeChanges` regularly. But store all the state in `MyPlugin`. Then, in `Renderer::synchronize()`, copy from `MyPlugin` to `MyRenderer`, so it can be used by the `MyGame`.

(although, I wouldn't do any gamelogic-related calculations in QML ever in the first place)

Comment: I agree.  Using Renderer::synchronize() to capture all state needed for the render thread to do a render while the main thread does something else is absolutely essential to use QQuickFramebufferObject correctly, and the fact the original poster didn't show one or think it was important enough to include sets alarm bells ringing with me; in fact they seem to be trying to move that logic elsewhere.  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html is essential reading.

Comment: I can certainly store state in MyPlugin whenever `makeChanges` is called. However, I cannot use a `synchronize` signal to copy from MyPlugin to MyRenderer/MyGame. As described above, only in the middle of the `MyGame::Redraw()` am I allowed to accept changes.